# What is need to make the partial reload after submiting so that no "refresh" or "F5" is needed for the user

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am working currently on a mvc - inline - editing which need to get some final touch and i cant get it to work as i really want to have:

The story is as following:

[image]

The user is presented with this screen and fills it out (Numbers)

[image]

After succesfull entering the numbers the partial view show update and look like this:
[image]

But becouse of there is no ajax/none of that I can figure out then there is no update at all and "ARROW" is only disappearing and looking like last image with i want to have a result:
[image]

The value in the database is updated correct and the last view can come if I refresh page/partialview.

My view consiste of a "view" and a partial view which is as following in shorting version:

First the View and javasection:

….

```
            <div id="partial">
                @Html.Partial("~PartialView_WaterUsageToDo.cshtml", Model)
            </div>

        </div>
```

Now the sction of the view:

And script section:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

             $('.edit').editable('/WaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode', {
                cssclass: 'jeditForm',
                tooltip: 'click to edit me...',
                width: 'none',
                height: 'none',
                onsubmit: function (settings, original) {
                    oldValue = original.revert;
                },
                submitdata: function () {
                    return {
                        id: $(this).data('id'),
                        PropertyName: $(this).data('propertyname')

                    }
                },
                callback: function (value, settings) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(value);
                    if (jsonData.status) {
                        $(this).text(jsonData.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).text(oldValue);
                    }
                }                
            })

            $('.editSelect').editable('/WaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode', {
                cssclass: 'jeditForm',
                tooltip: 'click to edit me...',
                width: 'none',
                height: 'none',
                type: 'select',
                submit: 'Ok',
                loadurl: '/hWaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode',
                loaddata: function () {
                    return { id: $(this).data('id') }
                },
                onsubmit: function (settings, original) {
                    oldValue = original.revert;
                },
                submitdata: function () {
                    return {
                        id: $(this).data('id'),
                        PropertyName: $(this).data('propertyname')
                    }
                },
                callback: function (value, settings) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(value);
                    if (jsonData.status) {
                        $(this).text(jsonData.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).text(oldValue);
                    }
                }
            }) 
            $('.editSelect').click(function () {
                $('select', this).addClass('form-control pull-left w100');
                $('button', this).addClass('btn btn-sm btn-success margin10')
            })            
    </script>
```

And the partial view which i want that make the refresh:

```
  @model IEnumerable<eMaja.Design.ViewModels.WaterUsageViewModel>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 50, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "waterUsageToReportGrid");
}
<div class="alert-success">@ViewBag.Message</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="divProcessing">
        <p>
            Processing, please wait ..
            <img src="../../eMajaContent/ajax-loader.gif">
        </p>
    </div>
    @grid.GetHtml(

    ...
    <script src="https://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.datepicker.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oldValue = '';
            var divProcessing = $("#divProcessing");
            // Hide the animated Gif when page loads:
            divProcessing.hide();
            $('#email').click(function () {
                // Required hack to get animated gif to run in IE:
                setTimeout(function () {
                    divProcessing.show();
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);
                $('myform').submit();
            });
            $('.edit').editable('/WaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode', {
                cssclass: 'jeditForm',
                tooltip: 'click to edit me...',
                width: 'none',
                height: 'none',
                onsubmit: function (settings, original) {
                    oldValue = original.revert;
                },
                submitdata: function () {
                    return {
                        id: $(this).data('id'),
                        PropertyName: $(this).data('propertyname')
                    }
                },
                callback: function (value, settings) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(value);
                    if (jsonData.status) {
                        $(this).text(jsonData.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).text(oldValue);
                    }
                } 


            })
            $('.editSelect').editable('/WaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode', {
                cssclass: 'jeditForm',
                tooltip: 'click to edit me...',
                width: 'none',
                height: 'none',
                type: 'select',
                submit: 'Ok',
                loadurl: '/hWaterUsage/WaterNumberReportedThisPeriode',
                loaddata: function () {
                    return { id: $(this).data('id') }
                },
                onsubmit: function (settings, original) {
                    oldValue = original.revert;
                },
                submitdata: function () {
                    return {
                        id: $(this).data('id'),
                        PropertyName: $(this).data('propertyname')
                    }
                },
                callback: function (value, settings) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(value);
                    if (jsonData.status) {
                        $(this).text(jsonData.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).text(oldValue);
                    }
                }
            })

             ...
        })
    </script>
}
```

If there is questions or comment to how to help solving this issues for me please let me know what is neede... and i will provide what is needed.

Best regards

Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not clear to me.
I think, you want to update part of the page. 
So you need to make a ajax request. 
Like 
$.ajax({
url:'your url',
data:12345,
success: function (result)
{`enter code here`}
})

In your controller return the partialview,
Then append it within success like this
$('#divid').html(result)